# Fast way of solving this iterative matrix equality in Python (with PyTorch)

Tags: python, performance, matrix, pytorch, causality

In one of my neural network implementations I have to solve the following problem:
`w = f(v)` with `Lv = q+Dw`, where `w`, `v`, `q` are vectors, `D` is a matrix and `L` is a diagonal matrix. This of course seems like a difficult dependency problem, but if we assume `D` is strictly lower triangular, the problem is iteratively solvable. For clarity I'll write out the problem below:

```
[l1  0  0 ... 0 ] [v1]     [ 0   0   0  ...  0] [w1]   [q1]
[ 0 l2  0 ... : ] [v2]     [D21  0   0  ...  :] [w2]   [q2]
[ 0  0 l3 ... : ] [v3]  =  [D31 D32  0  ...  :] [w3] + [q3]
[ :  :  : ... 0 ] [ :]     [ :   :   :       :] [ :]   [ :]
[ 0  0  0 ... ln] [vn]     [Dn1 Dn2 ...Dnn-1 0] [wn]   [qn]

[w1]     ( [v1] )
[ :] = f(  [ :]  )
[wn]     ( [vn] )
```

(I hope it is clear with the lack of math typesetting :P)

I solve this in a batch-wise setting, hence the vectors `w`, `v`, `q` are of the dimension `(N_batch, n)`.

As I'm not a python expert, I now only see the possibility to solve this using the following iterative procedure:

```
l = torch.diag(L)  # size: (n,)
vi = [ (1 / l[0]) * q[:, 0] ]  # size: (N_batch, 1)
for i in range(1, n):
    # building up the vector w out of v1 ... vi
    w = f(torch.stack(vi, dim=1))
    # calculate the new vi with the new w vector
    vi.append( (1 / l[0]) * ( q[:,i] + torch.einsum('j,bj->b', D[i,:i], w) ) )  
# final step
w1_n = f( torch.stack(vi, dim=1) )
```

This however takes up literally 85% of the time to calculate my one-step-forward procedure in the training of a neural network, hence it would be really nice to optimize this procedure :P

Is there some function I don't know that solves this, or is there some python guru around that can optimize my problem? Thanks in advance :D

MWE:

```
import torch
import time

n = 20
N_batch = 150
l = torch.rand(n)+1 # size: (n,)
q = torch.rand(N_batch, n)
f = torch.nn.Tanh()
D = torch.tril(torch.rand(n,n),diagonal=-1)

tic = time.time()
vi = [ (1 / l[0]) * q[:, 0] ]  # size: (N_batch, 1)
for i in range(1, n):
    # building up the vector w out of v1 ... vi
    w = f(torch.stack(vi, dim=1))
    # calculate the new vi with the new w vector
    vi.append( (1 / l[0]) * ( q[:,i] + torch.einsum('j,bj->b', D[i,:i], w) ) )
# final step
w1_n = f( torch.stack(vi, dim=1) )
print('Total time: ' + str(time.time()-tic))
```

Comment: By solve you mean find values of W, L, D that satisfy the equation?

Comment: the vector `q` and the matrices `L` and `D` are known, I want to obtain the values for `w`.